# Angular 2 - after running ng serve in command prompt, js files are not created in respective folder. What could be the reason?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 2 - after running ng serve in command prompt, js files are not created in respective folder. What could be the reason?(project is created using Angular-cli)

Comment: `ng serve` runs your project on a [webpack dev server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html). This means all the build files are in virtual memory in your machine. So you won't see them in your file structure

Comment: @LLai Thanks for quick reply. But page is not getting rendered; its blank. Also, there is no logs in console.

Comment: What steps are you going through? `ng serve`, then opening `localhost:4200`?

Comment: @LLai ng serve --open

Comment: you said the page is blank? What resources are loading? the index.html and the associated bundles?